# Xcode - deploying - cant see distribution in drop down for Edit Schema

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes

I've a total newbie to using XCode, I have been following this tutorial and got as far as Edit Schema to select Distribution from the drop down but all I can see is Debug and Release. Does anyone know why?

Here's the vid:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbabzWVvcvE

Answer (score 0):

You have to create scheme yourself and for distribution (aps store/ad hoc) that means duplicating Release scheme and setting code signing certificates under build settings for each of the new schemes.